# Prevent JQuery .HTML overwriting previous .HTML before its displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using a multi-dimensional array to store values and then loop round it based on if it meets two requirements does a number match and does it have a set state E.G 487 Online.

This changes in real time based on what event happens to be caught and inserted in the MD array on the server idea and everything is grand on that side of things.

Am trying to visual represent each state of a call in the following format:

1. If phone device is online turn tile red otherwise turn green and do .HTML.
2. If phone is ringing turn tile yellow and do .HTML.
3. If phone is in a call then turn the tile orange and do .HTML.
4. If phone just hangup then and do .HTML (but it doesn't do this) then turn blue via a css class using .addClass......then remove it after 3 seconds. (It wont display otherwise because status online gets caught right after so you dont even see it turn blue hence using a setTimeout to stop this.)

Steps 1 to 3 work accordingly the issue comes in with step 4.

The issue am having with this is am using JQuery .HTML to overwrite content in the tile every time the phone changes state but after some debugging and fiddling around I have found that the issue seems to be JQuery .HTML and/or how am using it and the setTimeOut I think but I don't know why.

***Problem is*** the Hangup event gets caught........ .HTML here doesn't seem to display and seems to get overwritten by the .HTML in the online event which gets caught straight after hangup and therefore displays .html from the online event instead.

I found when I remove the .HTML at step 1 it stops the issue, but I need it in step 1. But if I leave it there it seems to be overwriting the .HTML in step 4 which I also need for some reason.

Array looks like this with the extension number, SIP device status, current state the device is in e.g Ringing:

```
  [ '487', 'online', 'Hangup' ],
  [ '488', 'online' ],
  [ '477', 'online', 'Hangup' ] ]
```

What the server side events generally look like at the point where the event is caught:

```
477 and 487 both hungup
[ [ '487', 'online', 'Hangup' ], [ '477', 'online', 'Hangup' ] ]
something happened to a ChannelDestroyed
Channel Output ChannelDestroyed
something happened to an endpoint
EndpointStateChange
477 current state is: online
[ [ '487', 'online', 'Hangup' ], [ '477', 'online', 'Hangup' ] ]
```

Here is my code at the moment:

```
//Handles events to signal current call states aka if 488 dials 487 highlight both tiles with those values.
socket.on("eventsCalls", function (calldata) {
    for (var i = 0; i < calldata.length; i++) {
        if (calldata[i][0] && calldata[i][2] === "Ringing") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:contains('" + calldata[i][0] + "')").css("background-color", "yellow").append("<h4>User</h4><p>" + calldata[i][0] + " Is Ringing</p>");
        } else if (calldata[i][0] && calldata[i][2] === "Hangup") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:contains('" + calldata[i][0] + "')").html("<h4>User</h4><p>" + calldata[i][0] + " just hungup</p>").addClass("hangup");
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("div[class*='tile']").removeClass("hangup");
            }, 3000);
        } else if (calldata[i][0] && calldata[i][2] === "ANSWER") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:contains('" + calldata[i][0] + "')").css("background-color", "orange").html("<h4>User</h4><p>" + calldata[i][0] + " Is Busy</p>");
        }
    }
});
// Handles which sip devices are currently registered and displays them on the web page.
socket.on("eventsRegister", function (regisdata) {
    for (var i = 0; i < regisdata.length; i++) {
        if (regisdata[i][0] && regisdata[i][1] === "online") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:contains('" + regisdata[i][0] + "')").css("background-color", "green").html("<h4>User</h4><p>" + regisdata[i][0] + " Online</p>");
        } else if (regisdata[i][0] && regisdata[i][1] === "offline") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:contains('" + regisdata[i][0] + "')").css("background-color", "red").html("<h4>User</h4><p>" + regisdata[i][0] + " Offline</p>");
        }
    }
});
```

Is there any better alternatives or workarounds for this issue am having?

EDIT: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ltdbntu/3/) for an idea of what am trying to do its hard to replicate the catching of events but when it hits hangup the .html seems to be overwritten by Online event which seems to happen at the same time I think. It doesn't work like that for the last two events on my code the colors change but the .HTML for hangup seems to be overwritten by online.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle so it will easier to us to help you.

Comment: Hangup event gets caught........ .HTML here doesn't seem to display and seems to get overwritten by the .HTML in the online event which gets caught straight after hangup and therefore displays .html from the online event instead.

Comment: @Studento919 in your `setTimeout` you havent specified a delay .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: @MoshFeu Added a JSFiddle as you requested to replicate it as close as I can without the use of express and node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for certain, but your `setTimeout` is missing a `delay` parameter.

```
var hangupDelay = 5000; // 5 seconds. 
setTimeout(function () {
                $("div[class*='tile']").removeClass("hangup");
            }, hangupDelay );
```

This should remove the hangup class after 5 seconds anyway.

If you do not specify the `setTimeout` delay param; you get it almost instantly:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting

> delay is the number of milliseconds (thousandths of a second) that the
>   function call should be delayed by. If omitted, it defaults to 0. The
>   actual delay may be longer; see Notes below.

This might result in the hangup class instantly being removed and appearing to not be working.

Comment: Sorry forgot I removed it when I was fiddling with it, I have the delay already and the outcome remains the same which is extremely strange the background turns blue, it removes the class after the delay specified .......But as I said before it seems the online event is overwriting the .html before it displays, I have tested this and it seems to be the case.

Comment: @Studento919 could you show us the event fire order on the server side ? Also, try to use `if` on the hangup check, instead of `else if` as you can be online, and hangup!

Comment: I tried the IF to no avail I also put the server side code into this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2y22z8f/) as there is too much to insert into my question. Am using express and node.js. ave condensed it as much as possible based on my current but limited experience in using both. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Also inserted how the events generally look at the end of the hangup and where it seems to catch online and overwrite when it shouldn't